# Paypal API - PayPalNVP wrapper in PHP

Tags: php, api, paypal

I am using the Paypal API with a wrapper class (PayPalNVP) and am trying to get the resulting payment page at Paypal to show the item description and final total on the left hand side.  Right now it just shows nothing.

I am trying to pass the following vars to Paypal:

```
$paypal->setNVP("RETURNURL", "http://www.mysite.ca/confirm.php");
$paypal->setNVP("EMAIL", "$strPaypalEmail"); 
$paypal->setNVP("CURRENCYCODE", "CAD");
$paypal->setNVP("AMT", number_format($fltGrandTotal, 2));
$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0", "2013 Golf Registration");
$paypal->setNVP("L_DESC0", "2013 Golf Registration");
$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0", number_format($fltGrandTotal, 2));
$paypal->setNVP("ITEMAMT", number_format($fltGrandTotal, 2));
$paypal->setNVP("CUSTOM", $amount);
$paypal->setNVP("INVNUM", $orderID);
```

I would think this would set the description of the purchase to "2013 Golf Registration" and also show the final total... but it doesn't.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Request / Reponse as requested above:

```
Array
(
[TOKEN] => EC%2d8E276085HF4665733
[TIMESTAMP] => 2013%2d04%2d04T20%3a08%3a15Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 5b4a7f1b97a0a
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 51%2e0
[BUILD] => 5618210
[EMAIL] => xxx@xxx.com
[PAYERID] => XXXXX
[PAYERSTATUS] => verified
[FIRSTNAME] => John
[LASTNAME] => Smith
[COUNTRYCODE] => CA
[SHIPTONAME] => John Smith
[SHIPTOSTREET] => 123 Here
[SHIPTOSTREET2] => PO BOX 164
[SHIPTOCITY] => Here
[SHIPTOSTATE] => There
[SHIPTOZIP] => K1K1K1
[SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => CA
[SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => Canada
[ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
[CUSTOM] => 1%2e00
[INVNUM] => 9
)

Array
(
[TOKEN] => EC%2d8E276085HF4665733
[TIMESTAMP] => 2013%2d04%2d04T20%3a08%3a18Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 33790dbf25c30
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 51%2e0
[BUILD] => 5618210
[TRANSACTIONID] => 5V299088DL2402133
[TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
[PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
[ORDERTIME] => 2013%2d04%2d04T20%3a08%3a17Z
[AMT] => 1%2e00
[FEEAMT] => 0%2e33
[TAXAMT] => 0%2e00
[CURRENCYCODE] => CAD
[PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
[PENDINGREASON] => None
[REASONCODE] => None
)
```

Comment: Can you please get the Request and the Response you get from PayPal and post it up here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the original NVP Request in what you added (only Responses from PayPal)

But here's a set of example NVPs that would succeed:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=10.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=10.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=item name
```

Comment: I had the last two in my orig message

$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0", "Kids Come 1st - 2013 Golf Registration");

$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0", number_format($fltGrandTotal, 2));


I added the other two, but it makes no difference.

Comment: The original NVP request is not a call to setNVP on some class.  It is what that class actually produces and sends over the wire to the PayPal endpoint.  Without seeing that orignal request (nor having your class available to produce it) we can't duplicate your problem nor troubleshoot further.